# Align back button in the left and text in the center

Tags: react-native

I want to put the string 'example' in the middle of the header.

[image]

Code:

```
  <View style={viewStyle}>
      <ImageButton
        imageUrl={require('./assets/icons/Back-25.png')}
        onPress={props.onPressPhone}
      />
        <Text>{props.headerText}</Text>
    </View>
```

viewStyle:

```
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: 60,
    paddingTop: 15,
    shadowColor: '#000000',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 1 },
    shadowOpacity: 0.2,
    elevation: 2,
    position: 'relative',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
```

Image Button style:

```
alignSelf: 'center',
```

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to use a same-size empty .png image on the other side, and space-between in your header styling:

```
<View style={ styles.header }>
    <Button style={{left: 10}} onPress={ () => this.handlePress() }>
        <Image source={ require('../images/arrow_back.png') } style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} />
    </Button>
    <Text style={styles.header_text} >{this.props.title}</Text>
    <Button style={{right: 10}}>
        <Image source={ require('../images/no_image.png') } style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} />
    </Button>
</View>
```

and

```
header: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: width,
    backgroundColor: '#09146d',
},
```

...a bit kludgy, but it has worked for me. Alternatively, you could divide up the header with flex-based views, using [flexDirection: 'row'](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-direction-property) :

```
<View style={ styles.header }>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        //Button in here
    </View>
    <View style={{alignItems: 'center', flex: 6}}>
        //Text in here
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        //Nothing in here
    </View>
</View>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Modified flex worked for me, thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

Expand on kwishnu's flex idea:

- `flex: 1;` will always allocate only 1/3rd of the width to the title.  So use `flex: 1 1 auto;` instead to allow the title to expand into all available space.
- add `min-width: fit-content;` to the back button (so that the title will never cover the back button).
- Add bonus styling in the case where the title is really, really long

```css
span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="header" style="display: flex;">
    <span style="flex: 1; background: aqua; min-width: fit-content;">Back Button</span>
    <span style="flex: 1 1 auto; text-align: center; background: beige;">Edit title to see behaviour whien title is very long</span>
    <span style="flex: 1; background:red;"></span>
</div>
```